# JET/Esent: SeekEQ finds no matches with multi-column index and wildcards

Tags: c#, jet, esent, extensible-storage-engine

I have a 5-column table with a 2-column primary index.  Let's say the index is defined as (`Col1`, `Col2`).

In the the following snippet, **Api.TrySeek** returns **false** and I'm not sure why:

```
Api.JetSetCurrentIndex(session, table, null);

// this should match on Col1 = colVal1 and Col2 = *
Api.MakeKey(session, table, colVal1, MakeKeyGrbit.NewKey | MakeKeyGrbit.FullColumnStartLimit);

if (Api.TrySeek(session, table, SeekGrbit.SeekEQ)) // why is this false??
{
    Api.MakeKey(session, table, colVal1, MakeKeyGrbit.NewKey | MakeKeyGrbit.FullColumnEndLimit);

    if (Api.TrySetIndexRange(session, table, SetIndexRangeGrbit.RangeUpperLimit | SetIndexRangeGrbit.RangeInclusive))
    {
         <loop through entries in index range>
```

However, it returns **true** if I use **SeekGrbit.SeekGE**.  Could someone explain why?  Does `SeekEQ` not work with wildcard columns but `SeekGE` does?

In the loop, I've double-checked that the entries all have `Col1 == colVal1`, to rule out the possibility that it's just finding entries where `Col1 > colVal1`.